# Pass React props into javascript string

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm using Meteor with React. I'm trying to pull in a url from my database using props. It works ok when included within a div, but I want to copy a url to javascript string. It breaks when I do it though.

Ideally I could replace https://soundcloud.com/urlsting with *this.props.note.soundcloudUrl*

```
render() {
  if (this.props.note) {
  return (

    scPlayer.resolve('https://soundcloud.com/urlsting', function (track) {
      console.log(track);
      scPlayer.play();
    }),

    <div className="editor">
      <div className="editor__title">{this.props.note.title}</div>
      <div className="editor__body">{this.props.note.body}</div>
      <video autoPlay id="bgvid" loop>
        <source src={"https://" + this.props.note.dropboxUrl} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Define "it breaks".

Comment: It's possible that the issue is that it blows up when the component tries to render before the props string is set properly. Can you make a null check on the string before running `resolve()`?

Comment: @Emersonct I'm not sure I understand; props should be passed into the component. Did you mean trying to use the results of an async operation before it's completed (unrelated to props)?

Comment: If you're making a DB call, it's likely async. If you try to use the results of an async call before the call completes, you'll be using invalid data. You should render something during the call that doesn't break, and re-render after the call.

Comment: I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'note' of undefined"

Comment: Right. So try to do something like:
`props.note.soundcloudUrl 
?  scPlayer.resolve(props.note.soundcloudUrl, function (track) {
      console.log(track);
      scPlayer.play();
    })
: null`

That would return null if the prop was undefined, so it wouldn't break like it does now assuming that's the issue.

Comment: Sweet, that's it working. Thanks!